# How to prevent Current Limiting Circuit failing short?

Tags: power-supply, mosfet, switch-mode-power-supply, dc-dc-converter, protection

I am utilizing what I believe to be a fairly typical current limiting circuit at the input of a DC/DC converter.  I am driving the converter from a battery so I can never exceed a certain current or I risk damaging the battery.

The limiter is based off a recommended circuit from Art of Electronics. In the case of a short circuit at the load I have found that the limiting transistors dissipate a very large amount of heat and fail short.  Thus, the input current to the converter exceeds the rating of the battery. Is there a common way to make a current limiter that does not fail short?

[image: current limiter approximate circuit]

Comment: What converter? Many DC DC converter circuits can have a soft start to limit current inrush or limit current. I would take care of the current limiting at the DC DC converter. Or just use a large input cap to cover the current gap with maybe some filtering

Comment: A fuse makes for a pretty good current limiter that doesn't fail short.

Comment: Crappy boost converters can draw 10x rated load on startup. Which one is yours?  Then if current is insufficient to boost , it stalls

Comment: Fuses or PPTC are your best bets against failures. Buck converters are intrinsically limited against overcurrent (until the mosfet fails). Boost converters are only limited by coil resistance (i.e. not limited, in practice) so they need additional protection. Buck-boosts (4 mosfets) are limited by the controller but suffers from fried mosfets too. So, at the end of the game put a fuse on it. And if the load is important, a crowbar for overvoltage protection.

Comment: How about electronic fuse which completelly disconnect the load circuit? The curent limiter must to be too oversized to handle the longterm short. Or use fuse to take care about short, and curr. limiter to reduce pikes from battery.

Comment: You can use LM317 in current limiting mode. It has internal overheating protection. And TO-220 case easy to set heatsink. Just it needs more than 3V voltage to work properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, the current limit is set to turn on when the voltage on Rsens is enough to turn on Q2, or about 0.7 volts.  When shorted, your system does not shut down but continues to deliver this current into your short.  This means that your circuit has this current running through it, and has the full Vcc across it, so that the devices must dissipate a power in watts equal to Vcc times the current.  Even a small amount of power will blow transistors without heat sinks.

If you don't want to provide a big heat sink to allow your components to survive, and you don't want to limit current by switching, you might consider incorporating "self protected" mosfets into your analog current limit design in place of your standard discrete transistors.  These devices are self-protected to shut down from excessive temperature, overvoltage, and incorporate ESD protection and will either need to be toggled to re-start or start again only after the device has cooled down.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks John for the good advice on this!